# How to put data generated from multiple .get() events in chronological order

Tags: jquery, sorting

I'm not sure if this can be done with .get(), but I'd like to put the data generated from .get() in chronological order.

At the moment, my code pulls a blog title from each URL and displays it on another page in a div with the class ".blog-title-1".

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var fish = 'http://www.website.com/fish.html';
    var beach = 'http://www.website.com/beach.html';

    $.get(fish, function (data) {
        $.get(beach, function (data2) {
            $(data).find(".blog-title").appendTo(".blog-title-1");
            $(data2).find(".blog-title").appendTo(".blog-title-1");
        });
    });  
 });
```

Now, if a new post is added on the second URL (beach), it's just going to take the place of the blog title in the second position (data2). I would want it to appear at the top of the list since it's the newest blog post to be added out of all the blogs on the site.

Comment: That's what `prepend` or `prependTo` does, it inserts at the top

Comment: to achieve that, you'll probably need to pass the date of the 2 posts to be able to compare them. Maybe this information is already in data, if not, you'd have to add it.

Comment: @Kaddath The date can be extracted with .get() and comes in the format 8/25/2017.

Comment: hmm so it won't work if the 2 posts are published the same day, would be better with a timestamp, as the comparison will be easier too

Comment: Okay, to make things easier, is there an event handler such as .new()? If the function recognizes new data, .prependTo(".blog-title-1")?

Comment: i guess you cannot know that from the request itself in JS. With the way your code is written, `data2` will always arrive after `data`. It has to be in the informations sent from the 2 html files, and i don't know what's in them

Comment: @Kaddath, Okay, thank you for that information and your time!